# When opening Unity project, it is stuck on importing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project (2020.2.1f1) on both my home PC and a workplace PC (which is 64-bit aswell and has the same Unity version). It all worked fine until today, when I tried opening my Unity project from my external SSD on my workplace PC, the opening process got stuck on "Importing... (busy for )"

What I tried so far:

- Restarting my PC
- Deleting various files in a copy of the project, such as the library or the meta files (deleting those just led to the resulting project looking awful and all script implementations missing ect)

The upm.log file states:
[INFO] Resolving dependencies using SAT solver

The editor.log has a massive bunch of code, but the last line states:
[C:/PROJECTNAME/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.5/Editor/FileUtility.cs line 22]
(PROJECTNAME equals my project name which I dont wanna reveal here)

Anyone got an idea how I can get my project running again?

Comment: Just a word of warning: Never ever delete the meta files unless you are certain you want to do so. They contain the unique IDs and other information about assets which are used to resolve dependencies and more. Deleting them indeed means that references to assets will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this a few times and have typically been able to resolve it by deleting the package cache at /Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Local/Unity/cache before launching the editor.

Not sure what the root cause is though - so this is a workaround at best.

Answer (score -2):

Do you use Unity Hub?

If so, just uninstall the unity version you are using and reinstall it or a newer one.

Comment: You think that might help? I'm gonna try to just install a newer version and run it on there, thank you for the tip!